# Do cats purr for other animals?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

It's well known that cats purr for humans more than for other cats. But:

1. Would a cat purr if stroked by another humanoid animal, like a chimp?
2. Would a cat purr if stroked by a non-humanoid animal, like a dog?
3. Would a cat purr if stroked by a non-humanoid animal, with a known human close by?

Comment: #1=yes #2=yes #3=yes and to answer #1 & #2 we need to have #3 present to register it.